# AWS Amplify Configuration Error - Contact Administrator

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I set up a log in system on my web app using AWS AMPLIFY and when I try to log in, I get an error stating I have not configured authentication properly and please contact the administrator. It is working on my friends computer with the same code.
Any ideas on the issue here? Thanks!

I tried to delete my ui package and reinstall, and configure a new user, but neither helped.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and was driving myself crazy deleting and re-creating the app.

Simply running `npm upgrade` and then running `npm run dev` again, solved the issue for me.